# Why ambiguity only for overloaded operators and not for functions with "same" name but different scope?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Consider the example:

```
class Gfg { 
public: 
    void printHello() 
    { 
        cout << "hello gfg-class specific" << endl; 
    } 
}; 
  
void printHello() 
{ 
    cout << "hello gfg-global" << endl; 
} 
int main() 
{ 
    Gfg a; 
    a.printHello(); 
    printHello(); 
}
```

This code works fine.

But see other example for operator overloading, it will not compile.

```
class Gfg { 
public: 
    Gfg operator+(Gfg& a) 
    { 
        cout << "class specific + operator" << endl; 
        return Gfg(); // Just return some temporary object 
    } 
}; 

Gfg operator+(Gfg& a, Gfg& b) 
{ 
    cout << "global + operator called" << endl; 
    return Gfg(); // Just return some temporary object 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    Gfg a, b; 
    Gfg c = a + b; 
}
```

I thought in both cases name mangling(decoration) will make both name as unique name and member function will be given preference and hence member version of operator+ should be called, which doesn't happen. why?

Comment: The non-member `printHello` has absolutely nothing ambiguous about it, as anything relating to the member of the same name. `a.printHello();` can *only* refer to the member function, and `printHello();`, which is outside any context regarding `Gfg`, can only refer to the free-function. The same cannot be said for your operator overload. Both can apply, and the compiler has no definitive reason to choose one over the other; thus the ambiguity.

Comment: To add to @WhozCraig answer, this also has nothing to do with symbol mangling.

Comment: A side note: Reference parameters, which aren't meant to be changed in a function, should generally be `const`. Thsi will also help to avoid ambiguities with compiler generated constructors and operators for a class.

Answer (score 1):

The ambiguity resides in the use of `c = a+b;`. It is ambiguous because we do not know if we call the operator in the class (with one parameter) or the one outside the class (with two parameters). Using the call with the operator keyword clarifies a little bit: `c=a.operator+(b)` or `c =operator+(a,b)`.

Thus the ambiguity.

I modified your code like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class Gfg {
public:
    Gfg operator+(const Gfg& a)
    {
        cout << "class specific + operator" << endl;
        return Gfg(); // Just return some temporary object
    }
};

Gfg operator+(const Gfg& a, const Gfg& b)
{
    cout << "global + operator called" << endl;
    return Gfg(); // Just return some temporary object
}


int main()
{
    Gfg a, b,c,d;
    c = operator+(a,b); // equivalent to c = a+b
    c = a.operator+(b); // also equivalent to c=a+b

}
```

The code compiles and the output is the following :

```
global + operator called
class specific + operator
```

Comment: I liked the answer better before the edit. The last code does compile and the ambiguity is removed for the compiler, but at the price of ambiguity for the reader. Note that with `const Gfg a; Gfg b;` you can call either of the two with `a+b` or `b+a`, while `+` is expected to be symmetric. Eg: https://godbolt.org/z/5erzar

Comment: `this` can be considered as an implicit argument to member functions. In your member `operator+`, `this` is not `const`. If you declare `Gfg operator+(const Gfg& a) const` (as it should be) then the ambiguity is back

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I will put it back as before the edit then. Thanks very much for your correction

Comment: Put it back as before and indeed you are right about the ambiguity for the reader. Thanks again for your critical reading.